# How to edit a Python script?

Tags: python, sequence, primary-key, edit, fasta

I'm finding difficulties trying to edit a working python script.

I have 2 files:

1. a .txt file that contains IDs
2. a .fasta file that have Fasta sequences with their IDs.

The aim of this script is to compare the 2 files and once an ID from the first file match a sequence and its ID from the second file, the output should be the ID, the full sequence and its ID.

The script that I have here gets me the ID of the first file and the sequence text only without its ID, as an output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAWuO.jpg)

This is the script:

```
with open('uniprot_reviewed_taxonomy_9606.fasta', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
        if line.startswith('>'):
            full_name = line.split('|')
            accession_x = full_name[1]
            print(accession_x)
        else:
           print (line)

            with open('homosapiens_output1.txt', 'r') as f1:
                for line1 in f1.readlines()[1:]:  # ignores the first line
                    line1 = line1.replace("\n", "")

                    full_name1 = line1.split(' ')
                    accession_y = full_name1[0].replace(" ", "")
                    accession_z = full_name1[1].replace(" ", "")
                    main_accession = accession_x + " " + accession_z + " " + accession_y + " " + line

                    if accession_x == accession_z:
                        print(main_accession)
```

So can you please help me by editing the script **so can the output would be the ID, Fasta sequence and its ID?**

Comment: Just to clarify: you have file, let's say `ids.txt`, and it contains ids. And you have another file - `sequences.fasta` with sequences and their ids. And you want to create the third one, containing sequences and their ids that match ids from `ids.txt`, am I right? Another question `ids.txt` file does it contain sequences too, or only ids?

Comment: Yes exactly you are right! and the file ids.txt contains ids only. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is small test example how to do that.

Code:

```
# create test fasta:
test_content = """>tr|Q53XC5|Q53XC5_HUMAN Bone morphogenetic protein 4 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=BMP4 PE=2 SV=1
MIPGNRMLMVVLLCQVLLGGASHASLIPETGKKKVAEIQGHAGGRRSGQSHELLRDFEAT
LLQMFGLRRRPQPSKSAVIPDYMRDLYRLQSGEEEEEQIHSTGLEYPERPASRANTVRSF
HHEEHLENIPGTSENSAFRFLFNLSSIPENEVISSAELRLFREQVDQGPDWERGFHRINI
YEVMKPPAEVVPGHLITRLLDTRLVHHNVTRWETFDVSPAVLRWTREKQPNYGLAIEVTH
LHQTRTHQGQHVRISRSLPQGSGNWAQLRPLLVTFGHDGRGHALTRRRRAKRSPKHHSQR
ARKKNKNCRRHSLYVDFSDVGWNDWIVAPPGYQAFYCHGDCPFPLADHLNSTNHAIVQTL
VNSVNSSIPKACCVPTELSAISMLYLDEYDKVVLKNYQEMVVEGCGCR
>tr|A8K571|A8K571_HUMAN Bone morphogenetic protein 7 (Osteogenic protein 1), isoform CRA_b OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=BMP7 PE=2 SV=1
MHVRSLRAAAPHSFVALWAPLFLLRSALADFSLDNEVHSSFIHRRLRSQERREMQREILS
ILGLPHRPRPHLQGKHNSAPMFMLDLYNAMAVEEGGGPGGQGFSYPYKAVFSTQGPPLAS
LQDSHFLTDADMVMSFVNLVEHDKEFFHPRYHHREFRFDLSKIPEGEAVTAAEFRIYKDY
IRERFDNETFRISVYQVLQEHLGRESDLFLLDSRTLWASEEGWLVFDITATSNHWVVNPR
HNLGLQLSVETLDGQSINPKLAGLIGRHGPQNKQPFMVAFFKATEVHFRSIRSTGSKQRS
QNRSKTPKNQEALRMANVAENSSSDQRQACKKHELYVSFRDLGWQDWIIAPEGYAAYYCE
GECAFPLNSYMNATNHAIVQTLVHFINPETVPKPCCAPTQLNAISVLYFDDSSNVILKKY
RNMVVRACGCH
>tr|A8K660|A8K660_HUMAN Adiponectin OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=ADIPOQ PE=2 SV=1
MLLLGAVLLLLALPGHDQETTTQGPGVLLPLPKGACTGWMAGIPGHPGHNGAPGRDGRDG
TPGEKGEKGDPGLIGPKGDIGETGVPGAEGPRGFPGIQGRKGEPGEGAYVYRSAFSVGLE
TYVTIPNMPIRFTKIFYNQQNHYDGSTGKFHCNIPGLYYFAYHITVYMKDVKVSLFKKDK
AMLFTYDQYQENNVDQASGSVLLHLEVGDQVWLQVYGEGERNGLYADNDNDSTFTGFLLY
HDTN
"""

with open('test_sequences.fasta', 'w') as f:
    f.write(test_content)

# create test ids:
test_ids = 'A8K660\nQ53XC5\n'

with open('test_ids.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(test_ids)

# Load all sequences and store them in dict:

with open('test_sequences.fasta', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('>')

sequences = {}
for seq in lines:
    if seq:
        id_ = seq[: seq.find('\n')].split('|')[1]
        seq = seq[seq.find('\n')+1:]
        sequences[id_] = seq

# import ids:
with open('test_ids.txt', 'r') as f:
    ids = f.readlines()
    ids = [id_.strip() for id_ in ids]  # remove \n from id end

# checking ids
# and filter out those that are not in sequences dict

filtered_ids = [id_ for id_ in ids if id_ in sequences.keys()]

# writing new file with filtered sequences:

with open('filtered_ids.txt', 'w') as f:
    for id_ in filtered_ids:
        f.write('>|' + id_ + '\n')
        f.write(sequences[id_])

# the final function:

def ids_filter(ids_file, seq_file, out_file):
    with open(seq_file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().split('>')

    sequences = {}
    for seq in lines:
        if seq:
            id_ = seq[: seq.find('\n')].split('|')[1]
            seq = seq[seq.find('\n')+1:]
            sequences[id_] = seq

    with open(ids_file, 'r') as f:
        ids = f.readlines()
        ids = [id_.strip() for id_ in ids]

    filtered_ids = [id_ for id_ in ids if id_ in sequences.keys()]

    with open(out_file, 'w') as f:
        for id_ in filtered_ids:
            f.write('>|' + id_ + '\n')
            f.write(sequences[id_])
```

Comment: Great!Thank you so much for helping! :D